# Fix plotly ggplotly() Title Overlapping Plot When Title is Split on Two Lines

Tags: javascript, r, plot, plotly

In the example below, the second line of the title overlaps slightly with the plot. Is there a way to fix this by increasing the spacing between the title and plot?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("A REALLY, REALLY, REALLY LONG TITLE THAT I WANT TO\nSPLIT INTO TWO LINES")
p1

ggplotly() %>% config(collaborate=FALSE, cloud=FALSE, displaylogo=FALSE, modeBarButtonsToRemove=c("select2d", "sendDataToCloud", "pan2d", "resetScale2d", "hoverClosestCartesian", "hoverCompareCartesian", "lasso2d", "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d"))
```

[image: overlapping plotly title]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plotly ignores trailing new line characters and also needs HTML breaks `<br />` instead of `\n` for new lines (see example at the end).

Add `<br />` to manually break your title and add a top `margin` to your layout (`layout(gp, margin=list(t = 75))`).

[image: that works]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("A REALLY, REALLY, REALLY LONG TITLE THAT I WANT TO <br />\nSPLIT INTO TWO LINES<br />\n")
p1

gp <- ggplotly() %>% config(collaborate=FALSE, cloud=FALSE, displaylogo=FALSE, modeBarButtonsToRemove=c("select2d", "sendDataToCloud", "pan2d", "resetScale2d", "hoverClosestCartesian", "hoverCompareCartesian", "lasso2d", "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d"))
gp <- layout(gp, margin=list(t = 75))
gp
```

---

**ggplot**
[image: ggplot]

---

**plotly**

[image: plotly]

Answer (score -3):

As you can tell, ggplot doesn't recalculate the total absolute height. So, the easiest way to add some buffer space between the title and plot is to simply add an **additional newline char** (`\n`) on the end of a long title.

`ggtitle("A REALLY, REALLY, REALLY LONG TITLE THAT I WANT TO\nSPLIT INTO TWO LINES\n")`